# OpenCV - How to compute the percent of dark color in image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to filter images by computing the percent of dark color in images.

The percent of dark color in this image is 0.05%, for example:

[image]

And the percent of dark color in second image is 0.5%:

[image]

Comment: Proportation compared to the rest of the image? You could go through all the pixelvalues and count them if they are "dark" enough.

Comment: `import numpy as np; np.countNonZero(img)`

Comment: @user1767754 Can you give some example code?

Comment: if it is a binary image use countNonZero as @ZdaR says, else, use threshold to convert to binary image and then countNonZero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [threshold to zero](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#threshold-to-zero) to set dark pixels to zero then use [cv::countNonZero()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) to count non-zero values.

```
double getBlackProportion(cv::Mat img, double threshold)
{
    int imgSize = img.rows * img.cols;
    // you can use whathever for maxval, since it's not used in CV_THRESH_TOZERO
    cv::threshold(img, img, threshold, -1, CV_THRESH_TOZERO);
    int nonzero = cv::countNonZero(img);


    return (imgSize - nonzero) / double(imgSize);
}
```